# pushing information to an open web page

Tags: html, web

I want to push information on to my web page in real time. for example, if I have a ticker that counts the number of people who have visited my site.

I want that ticker to change whenever someone o open s  the page in real time without having to refresh the page.

I imagine that this could be done using ajax and checking for updated information every few seconds and them updating the page asynchronously... but I feel like there is an easier way.

Is there a technology I could use to accomplish this task?

Comment: WebSockets is a way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on http://socket.io/ WebSockets implementation.